# How to use index column for multiple tables with a single statement in datatable js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatable js for 2 tables in a single page.

HTML

```
<!-- Table#1 -->
<table class="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>col1</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>val1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>val3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- Table#2 -->
<table class="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>col1</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>val1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>val3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    var t = $('table.dataTable').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );

    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();

});
```

It's showing the index column only in first table.
How can I display it?

I know it's possible by using two different id on the tables. But, in that case I've to copy the javascript code again. If I want to use another table need to copy it once more.

Is there any way to use it for all tables by using the javascript code once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want the two tables to be numbered independently of each other.

If so, then `this` in the event handler should refer to whichever table the event relates to, and `t.table(this)` will select "this" table from the tables held in `t`.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var t = $('table.dataTable').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        }],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.table(this).column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        });
    }).draw();
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).column is not a function.
Getting this error.

Comment: @user1710782, I've had a hack at the answer. Take another look.

Comment: Goes to show the value of actually reading the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use the [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method in order to access a jQuery object by its index. And eq indices start from 0.

```
var numTables = $(table).length
$(document).ready(function() { 
    for(var i =0; i < numTables; i++){     
    var t = $('table.dataTable').eq(i).DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );

    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
}

});
```

Comment: There 'table' is missing on 1st line. I've fixed that but not working.

Comment: changed `$('table.dataTable').eq(i + 1)` to `$('table.dataTable').eq(i)` since eq is zero-indexed....

Comment: I'm sorry. Still it's not working. Thank you for your great effort.